# Php: Iterate over dir path and create folder if not exist

Tags: php, path, iterator, directory

I want to make sure each folder in path exist.

```
$Path = "NamFdr1/NamFdr2/NamFdr3/NamImj.jpg"
```

E.g.:

- First check that `"NamFdr1"` exists, if not create it;
- Then check that `"NamFdr2"` exists, if not create; and so on.

How can I do this with built-in functions?

Comment: `mkdir("NamFdr1/NamFdr2/NamFdr3", 0777, true)` where 'true' is the 'recursive' parameter of [mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
 if (!file_exists('NamFdr1/NamFdr2/NamFdr3')) 
 {
     mkdir('NamFdr1/NamFdr2/NamFdr3', 0777, true);
 }
```

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for...